# how to add polygons in shapefile in R

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, data-visualization

I have a few building data in shapefile. Now I want to add some small circules/rectangles/anything suitable to represent the lighting poles beside the building. How could I do that in R.

Currently I read in the shapefile in R by readOGR command. 
and display it in shiny as below:
[image: shiny]

After adding the lighting poles, it should look like:
[image]

Moving forward, the size of the circle should be the brightness of the lighting. Could anyone kindly advise how to implement this or which package is useful to do it?
Thank you!

Comment: Two things. 1) Do you have data for the lighting poles including degrees of brightness? 2) Can you provide you data and code?

Comment: the data and shapefile are on my company laptop, I am not able to post here, would appreciate if anyone can provide an direction or recommend a package for me to learn

Comment: It is usually best to use `dput()`. This is a function in R. If you struggle in uploading data, you can upload your data in external places if you want (e.g., googledrive). I have seen some people doing it.